# SQL: Trigger Substring on string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table in SQL with badwords and his ids, and also I've got a table with properties of photos of a gallery. I want to make a trigger that dont let you insert a photo with bad words on the photo.title and on the photo.description. How can I do it??

```sql
CREATE TABLE Photos ( photoId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(512), date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, url VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL, visibility VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, userId INT, FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId), CONSTRAINT ValidVisibility CHECK (visibility in ('Public', 'Private')) ); 
CREATE TABLE BadWords ( wordId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );
```

Comment: please add a sample of your tables, and what is the criteria of 'badwords' ?

Comment: The idea is a filter that dont let you put insults in the title and the description of the photo. My tables are:
CREATE TABLE Photos (
 photoId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
 description VARCHAR(512),
 date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 url VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
 visibility VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 userId INT,
 FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId),
 CONSTRAINT ValidVisibility CHECK (visibility in ('Public', 'Private'))
);
CREATE TABLE BadWords (
 wordId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

Comment: please post question details (e.g.: table definition) by editing your question rather than as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** make a trigger on insertion that will do this select:

```
 SELECT * FROM Photos, BadWords 
  
 WHERE  Photos.title LIKE CONCAT('%', BadWords.word ,'%') OR

        Photos.description LIKE CONCAT('%', BadWords.word ,'%')
```

and delete all results. (the select is checking if title or description contains a value from the BadWords.word column
)

Comment: Right now I tried this and it works when the word is isolated:  

DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triggerBadWords
BEFORE INSERT ON photos
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE photoswithbadwords INT;
SET photoswithbadwords = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BadWords WHERE (new.title LIKE BadWords.word) OR (new.description LIKE BadWords.word));
if (photoswithbadwords>0) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '¡Modera tu lenguaje amigo!';
END if;
END //
DELIMITER;
I've tried with the '%' like this: "LIKE BadWords.word + '%'" but I got this error: "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '%' "

Comment: try add it like this: `Photos.title LIKE '%' + BadWords.word + '%' OR  Photos.description LIKE 
'%' + BadWords.word + '%'  `

Comment: Same error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '%'

Comment: try to turn off `strict mode`

Comment: what DB are you using ?

Comment: same... :(, there is not any other way to represent any character without using '%' ?

Comment: I'm using heidisql

Comment: heidisql is the client softwere what is your DB server ?

Comment: OK I hope this will do the trick - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93d0e/5
I also edited the answer

Comment: please click the check on my answer, thanks